# exim4 and postfix cannot both exists?

Tags: centos, postfix, exim

Server is CentOS 6

I installed exim4 as mta in my local server.

and I can simple send mail by mail command(`mailx`):

```
echo 'a test mail' | mail -s 'a subject' me@xxx.com
```

then I installed postfix, but not running.

Now the exim4 is running, and listen port 25 is exim4.

But I can't mail, with error:

```
postdrop: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory
```

and the blocked mail is in `/var/spool/postfix/maildrop`.

I search and know to fix this error with mkfifo this file.

But I don't know, the postfix is not running, and exim4 is running, how does postfix prevent me from send mail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is likely triggered from the [alternatives](http://linux.die.net/man/8/alternatives) system.

Simply installing postfix may have made that default MTA (by updating the symbolic link `/usr/lib/sendmail`) and because postfix was not yet configured nor running --> instant error.

You can resolve that by running `alternatives --config mta` and restoring Exim as the default.

Comment: Very thanks. I use `alternatives --display mta` and link currently points to /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix, after `yum remove postfix`, link currently points to /usr/sbin/sendmail.exim